# Updating value of one field on change of value of other field

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

I am using a Joomla form add-on.

the form already captures logged-in user-name on submit.
Now I want to create two fields

1. verified- a button field, which allows me to add javascript code for the button.
2. Verified by - (it can be a calc field type, where I can use both Javascript and PHP)
   Every time the button verified is clicked, the verified by field captures the logged in user's name, if the button is clicked second time by another user, it adds the name of that second user in the verified by field, not overwrite it.

Comment: Could you clarify with the form extension you're using, the version of Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but from the sound of the question's title you might want to check out [MySQL triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).